# Multiple matches and multiple excludes in regular expressions in R using PCRE

Tags: r, regex, pcre

I am pretty new to regular expressions in R and I am trying to match a vector of strings including some patterns and excluding some patterns. I searched on stackoverflow and it seems that no similar questions have been asked. Here is the vector of string `mystring` to be matched.

```
mystring <- c("fhwjantdesd", "unwanted", "fdedsifrfed", "undesired", "sdsyessd", "yedsfd")
```

In this `mystring` I want to figure out if `mystring` includes any permutation of 6 letters of "wanted" excluding the string "wanted". Similarly, includes any permutation of the 7 letters of "desired" and 3 letters of "yes" excluding the string "desired" and "yes".

So the expected output of `grepl(pattern, mystring, perl = TRUE)` should be:

```
[1] TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE
```

I want to use the `perl` option of grepl, which could speed up the function. Does anyone could provide some clues on this `pattern`? And could you explain what does each part of the pattern means cos I am just a starter in using PCRE. Thanks

Comment: Re "*I want to use the `perl` option of grepl, which could speed up the function*", It could also slow it down, which I find more likely.

Comment: does this solve your issue?

Comment: @Hardikgupta Thanks Hardik for your answer. That could solve my problem. But I am wondering if there is a `grepl()` answer with perl option. Let's wait if anybody could give that kind of answer.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for your information. Does that mean even if I use the `grepl()` without the perl choice, it could be faster than the `grepl()` function with the perl choice in R?

Comment: Yes, it could..

Comment: Don't use regex matching. 1) Join each word with `|` to form a regex pattern. 2) For each word and for each string, create a counted set from its letters. 3) For each string, check if it matches the previously created regex pattern. If not, check if its counted set is a superset of the counted set of one of the words. If so, it's match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below code will work with some limitation.

```
grepl("(^((?!yes|wanted|desired).)*$)", mystring, perl=TRUE)
```

It will only exclude above words. That is according to your data.

Comment: Thanks @PIG for your answer. Could you explain a little about the limitation of the above code?

Comment: 1) That matches the string `abc` even though it shouldn't. 2) It's a rather inefficient approach to do what it does; the R equivalent of `map { !/yes|wanted|desired/ } @mystring` would make far more sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
mystring <- c("fhwjantdesd", "unwanted", "fdedsifrfed", "undesired", "sdsyessd", "yedsfd")
Status <- NULL
str <- c("wanted", "desired", "yes")
index <- 1


for (i in mystring) {
  for (j in str) {
    char_length <- nchar(j)

    if (is.na(str_extract(string = i, pattern = j)) | str_extract(string = i, pattern = j) == F) {
      if (sum(unlist(strsplit(j, "")) %in% unlist(strsplit(i, ""))) >=  char_length) {
        Status[index] <- T
        break
      }
    }
  }

  if (is.na(Status[index])) {
    Status[index] = F
  }

  index <- index + 1
}

Status

  > Status
[1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```